# define struct to make two members hold the same value

Tags: c, struct

how to organize the jo struct to make the member c get the value of gpr[0].a when I give a number to gpr[0].a in main function. It seems I can not use '=' to make them hold the same value in the definition of structure.
**Don't change the main function, just reorganize the struct jo**, get the result ou.c =1, ou.d =2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    union {
        double a;
        int b;
    } gpr[2]; 
    double c, d;
} jo;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    jo ou;

    ou.gpr[0].a = 1;
    ou.gpr[1].a = 2;

    printf("%f\n", ou.c);
    printf("%f\n", ou.d);

    return 0;
}
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: "Don't change the main function, just reorganize the struct jo, get the result ou.c =1, ou.d =2"... Thank you for your order, would you like fries with that?

Comment: If you want `c` contain the value of `a`, assign it to `c`; simplest way.

Comment: @MD XF ,Yes, how to write the struct, just make them hold the same value

Comment: You can't. A struct definition has no such ability. What you can do is to have a setter function or a macro that does that for you. So instead of setting `a` directly the function/macro would be called to do that which sets both `a` and `c`. Or I guess you could define your own extension to C and get it approved by the C standards committee. Whichever is easier for you.

Comment: @kaylum: "You can't" is an answer not a comment.  Then I could downvote it for being wrong.

Comment: @dave Fair point. I guess I misunderstood the intent of the question. I thought OP really does need separate `a` and `c` fields. But your interpretation does seem reasonable and is probably on the money. Good on you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is being done to test your knowledge of unions.  So currently you have a union of `a` and `b` in an array of length two.  Now we need the `gpr[0]` to be the same as `c` and `gpr[1]` to be the same as `d`.

So, each member of the array is of length `sizeof(double)` and there are two of them.  So we need a struct that is 2 doubles (`c` and `d`) to be unioned with the `gpr[2]` variable.

Thus this should work:

```
typedef struct {
     union {
          struct {
              double c;
              double d;
          };
          union {
              double a;
              int b;
          } gpr[2];
   };
} jo;
```

We have to use anonymous structs and unions or the code has to change for us to reference the members.